# Is there a command which can "undo" the results of ALT+FN+1+3 on my laptop? It reduced the size of my screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, resolution, display-settings

(I have an ASUS laptop (Notebook U46E Series, 64-bit OS, Win7 Home Premium Edition, Service Pack 1))

PROBLEM: I keyed in the following: ALT+FN+1+3 and immediately my screen was reduced in size and I lost the background of my desktop (but the desktop icons are still fine).

QUESTION 1: What is the command which can "undo" this and restore my screen to its normal state?

(Background: I had been following some instructions which I had found on the internet for how to create a musical note symbol. It said, for a laptop, to input ALT+FN+1+3. I am angry at myself that I did not read the instructions more closely.  I was supposed to use the 1 and 3 ON the laptop's Querty, and NOT use the numbers ABOVE the Querty, but, alas, I used the numbers above the Querty.)

(The only thing I tried on my own was CTRL+Z and that did nothing that I could see.)

Update: I contacted ASUS Support and they had me go into Display and adjust the resolution from 1024x768 to the highest resolution, 1366x768. I admit it did bring me back to having a full screen.  YET, I want to know--was this a sufficient solution?  Is my laptop compromised in any way? And so, next question--

QUESTION 2: Is 1366x768 a stable resolution?

BOTTOM LINE: I just wish ASUS could have given me a command to "undo" the results of ALT+FN+1+3, instead of fiddling with the resolution. Does anyone know the command for this? Thanks for any help/advice/reassurance!

Answer (score 0):

No, your laptop was not compromised by setting the resolution to it's proper setting. I've never heard of that combination of hotkeys, but it's probably something that is proprietary to that Asus series, like switching to a second set of display settings.

I highly suspect simply pressing the hotkey combination again would have fixed it, or cycled through a number of settings with each press before returning to normal.

To more definitively  answer question #2, your monitor has a resolution called the "native resolution". It is the highest (and best) resolution the monitor can support. It is usually the highest setting in the Screen Resolution menu.

Asus support was correct, hopefully it didn't take you hours on the phone for them to give you this proper fix!

Comment: Moses--Thank-you for your reassuring response!

Comment: After re-reading your question, you likely invoked this behavior with the combination of `FN+F1` or `FN+F2`. If you look at your keyboard, there are likely icons on the F1, F2, or F3 keys that indicate (nebulously) what combining that particular key with the FN key will do. One of them is likely an external monitor setting that you invoked.

Comment: If it helps in explaining my unsought adventure today, I did not press any of the function keys across the very top of the keyboard.  I pressed <ALT> + <FN> (which is a key at the bottom of the keyboard (a special ASUS key, perhaps?)) + the number key 1 + the number key 2.

Comment: Oops, I meant number key 3, not number key 2.

Comment: That key combination might be something like "Switch to monitor #..." but only your model's user manual would be able to tell you that. Manufacturers make their combinations different in many circumstances.